# integer valued equation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have to enumerate the solutions of the following system of equations

$$
\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}+\cdots+\alpha_{k}=j\\
\alpha_{1}+2\alpha_{2}+\cdots+k\alpha_{k}=n,
$$

where $k$ is a fixed integer and $n\geq k$ and $0\leq j\leq n$. The unknowns, $\alpha_{i}$, are non negative integers.

Moreover, what is the connection between such solutions and the solutions of the system

$$
\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}+\cdots+\alpha_{k}=j\\
\alpha_{1}+2\alpha_{2}+\cdots+k\alpha_{k}=n-1\qquad ?
$$

Can you shed light on this?

Comment: well the first equation is to do with partitions of integers. So you ask how many partitions of the integer $j$ are there, and then you'll possibly want to allow swaps of the solutions, like permuting the $\alpha_i$'s. I'm not sure about the second immediately. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29

Answer (score 1):

The second equation (changing $a_i$ to $x_i$ for personal preference)
$$ x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 + ... + kx_k = n$$

specifies partitions of $n$ using numbers not more than $k$. This is easy to see if you think of $x_i$ as representing the number of $i$'s in your partition. That is, your partition has $x_1$ ones, $x_2$ twos, and so on. The first equation

$$ x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_k = m$$

specifies weak compositions of $m$ into $k$ parts (by definition). But forget about that. Considering equation 2, the sum of $x_1 + x_2 + ...$ is the number of parts in your partition of $n$. So the two equations together give you **partitions of $n$ into $m$ parts using integers less than or equal to $k$**, which we will denote $P(n,m,k)$.

There is a lot of literature on enumerating partitions which I won't discuss, but you can simply do a recursive construction, incrementing $x_i$ or moving on to $x_{i+1}$. If you just want to instead count such partitions, we get a natural recurrence formula by breaking them into two cases: whether or not the last (biggest) part equals $k$.

$$ P(n,\,m,\,k) = P(n-k,\,m-1,\,k) + P(n,\,m,\,k-1) $$